# Python 3.5.5 running under Wine sets environment variable with empty string name

Tags: python, wine

Hi I need to run Python under Wine (deployment on CI) and I encounter following weird behaviour.
If I run python interpreter inside wine as follows (clearing linux env):

```
env -i wine cmd /C python
```

I get this in os.environ:

```
>>> print(list(os.environ))
['WINELOADERNOEXEC', 'SYSTEMDRIVE', 'PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE', 'PROCESSOR_LEVEL', 'PATHEXT', 'PROGRAMFILE
S', 'PROMPT', 'HOMEPATH', 'SYSTEMROOT', 'OS', 'PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER', 'HOMEDRIVE', 'WINDIR', 'USERPROFIL
E', 'TMP', '', 'USERDOMAIN', 'COMSPEC', 'PROCESSOR_REVISION', 'NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS', 'COMMONPROGRAMFILE
S', 'ALLUSERSPROFILE', 'APPDATA', 'LOGONSERVER', 'SESSIONNAME', 'PUBLIC', 'CLIENTNAME', 'WINSYSDIR', 'US
ERNAME', 'TEMP', 'PROGRAMDATA', 'COMPUTERNAME', 'LOCALAPPDATA', 'PATH']
```

As you can see there is variable with key '' which is a problem, because lot of python code (e.g. subprocess module actually checks for this and dies on exception of having invalid environment variables).

If I check actual windows environment using SET I don't get this variable:

```
$ env -i wine cmd /C SET
ALLUSERSPROFILE=C:\users\Public
APPDATA=C:\users\bruno\Application Data
CLIENTNAME=Console
CommonProgramFiles=C:\Program Files\Common Files
COMPUTERNAME=schrot
ComSpec=C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe
HOMEDRIVE=C:
HOMEPATH=\users\bruno
LOCALAPPDATA=C:\users\bruno\Local Settings\Application Data
LOGONSERVER=\\schrot
NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS=8
OS=Windows_NT
PATH=C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\windows\system32\wbem;C:\Program Files\Miniconda3;C:\Program File
s\Miniconda3\Scripts;C:\Program Files\Miniconda3\Library\bin
PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH
PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE=x86
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=x86 Family 6 Model 158 Stepping 9, GenuineIntel
PROCESSOR_LEVEL=6
PROCESSOR_REVISION=9e09
ProgramData=C:\ProgramData
ProgramFiles=C:\Program Files
PROMPT=$P$G
PUBLIC=C:\users\Public
SESSIONNAME=Console
SystemDrive=c:
SYSTEMROOT=C:\windows
TEMP=C:\users\bruno\Temp
TMP=C:\users\bruno\Temp
USERDOMAIN=schrot
USERNAME=bruno
USERPROFILE=C:\users\bruno
windir=C:\windows
WINELOADERNOEXEC=1
winsysdir=C:\windows\system32
```

Further investigation shows that the os.environ is being initialised already by posixmodule.c in cpython implementation.

I would be OK with workaround but if I actually attempt to delete '' variable in python the os.environ class prevents from doing so as '' is considered invalid variable:

```
>>> del os.environ['']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\Miniconda3\lib\os.py", line 738, in __delitem__
    del self._data[encodedkey]
  File "C:\Program Files\Miniconda3\lib\os.py", line 776, in <lambda>
    if "unsetenv" not in __all__:
OSError: [Errno 0] Error
```

Do you have any suggestion how to work around this problem (I can fill this as a bug report to usptream python or perhaps Wine, but I'd like to get it working in the meantime)

Answer (score 0):

I have figured an ugly workaround is to do following and start of each python script:

```
del os.environ._data['']
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a job for the `sitecustomize` module.  From the Python documentation ([The Customization Modules](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/appendix.html?highlight=sitecustomize#the-customization-modules)):

> […] Now you can create a file named `usercustomize.py` in that directory and put anything you want in it. It will affect every invocation of Python, unless it is started with the `-s` option to disable the automatic import.
>
> `sitecustomize` works in the same way, but is typically created by an administrator of the computer in the global site-packages directory, and is imported before `usercustomize`. See the documentation of the [site](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/site.html#module-site) module for more details.

So finding the global site-packages directory for your Python installation and create a `sitecustomize.py` with the following content will fix the problem for each and every script in one place:

```
import os
del os.environ._data['']
```